# Relative week to this date

Tags: javascript

when I receive date. 
I want to know if this date is in the next week or in 2 weeks or in this week.

I thought to find the week number of year and calculate

```
 getWeek(date)-getWeek(new Date())
```

with this function

```
var getWeek = function(date) {
    var onejan = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    return Math.ceil((((date - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
  };
```

. but my problem is with january. that if I look in december on dates in january it will cause problem.

Their is simple way in js to do this?

Comment: add more explaination to your question ,like code and where you are stuck.else it doesnt match the question guideline of SO

Comment: What you want current week of the given date?

Comment: I think the easiest way is you will get timestamp of 2 days, and divide it by `7*24*60*60*1000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with finding out the date value of Sunday in each week:

```
function getSunday(d) {
  var t = new Date(d);
  return new Date(t.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) - (t.getDay() * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
}
```

Now if you subtract two sundays, and divide by the number of milliseconds in a week (*7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000*), you'll get your answer:

```js
function getSunday(d) {
  var t = new Date(d);
  return new Date(t.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) - (t.getDay() * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
}

function getWeekOffset(d1, d2) {
  d1 = getSunday(d1);
  d2 = getSunday(d2);

  return (d2 - d1) / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}

alert(getWeekOffset(new Date('2015-12-26T03:24:00'), new Date('2016-01-04T07:00:00')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [JavaScript Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
But be aware that JavaScript uses the system time of the client. That means, two computers sitting next to each other may generate different results.

Comment: This could have been a comment. It does not answer the OP in any way.

Comment: I disagree. The OP specifically asked for an easy way to handle date problems. That is exactly what the JavaScript date object is for.